# Sequentially extract top n from group depending on group value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I am working on calculating some football stats.

I have the following dataframe:

```
{'Player': {8: 'Darrel Williams',  2: 'Mark Ingram',  3: 'Michael Carter',  4: 'Najee Harris',  10: 'James Conner',  0: 'Buffalo Bills',  15: 'Davante Adams',  1: 'Aaron Rodgers',  5: 'Tyler Bass',  11: 'Corey Davis',  6: 'Van Jefferson',  14: 'Matt Ryan',  7: 'T.J. Hockenson',  9: 'Antonio Brown',  12: 'Alvin Kamara',  13: 'Tyler Boyd'}, 'Position': {8: 'RB',  2: 'RB',  3: 'RB',  4: 'RB',  10: 'RB',  0: 'DEF',  15: 'WR',  1: 'QB',  5: 'K',  11: 'WR',  6: 'WR',  14: 'QB',  7: 'TE',  9: 'WR',  12: 'RB',  13: 'WR'}, 'Score': {8: 24.9,  2: 18.8,  3: 16.2,  4: 15.3,  10: 13.9,  0: 12.0,  15: 11.3,  1: 10.48,  5: 9.0,  11: 8.8,  6: 6.9,  14: 1.68,  7: 0.0,  9: 0.0,  12: 0.0,  13: 0.0}}
```

| Player | Position | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Darrel Williams | RB | 24.9 |
| Mark Ingram | RB | 18.8 |
| Michael Carter | RB | 16.2 |
| Najee Harris | RB | 15.3 |
| James Conner | RB | 13.9 |
| Buffalo Bills | DEF | 12 |
| Davante Adams | WR | 11.3 |
| Aaron Rodgers | QB | 10.48 |
| Tyler Bass | K | 9 |
| Corey Davis | WR | 8.8 |
| Van Jefferson | WR | 6.9 |
| Matt Ryan | QB | 1.68 |
| T.J. Hockenson | TE | 0 |
| Antonio Brown | WR | 0 |
| Alvin Kamara | RB | 0 |
| Tyler Boyd | WR | 0 |

What I am looking to do, given the following `requirements_dictionary`, is to extract the top `value` (`Score` in the dataframe) for each `key` (`Position` in the dataframe):

`requirements_dictionary = {'QB': 1, 'RB': 2, 'WR': 2, 'TE': 1, 'K': 1, 'DEF': 1, 'FLEX': 2}`

What makes this challenging, is that for the final `key`, `FLEX`, that matches to *no position in the dataframe*, because that value *could be* a position of: `RB, WR,` or `TE`.

Final output should look like:

| Player | Position | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Darrel Williams | RB | 24.9 |
| Mark Ingram | RB | 18.8 |
| Michael Carter | RB | 16.2 |
| Najee Harris | RB | 15.3 |
| Buffalo Bills | DEF | 12 |
| Davante Adams | WR | 11.3 |
| Aaron Rodgers | QB | 10.48 |
| Tyler Bass | K | 9 |
| Corey Davis | WR | 8.8 |
| T.J. Hockenson | TE | 0 |

Since that is the top `2 RB, 1 QB, 2 WR, 1 TE, 1 K, 1 DEF` and `2 FLEX`.

I have tried the following code which gets me close:

`all_points.groupby('Position')['Score'].nlargest(2)`

```
Position    
DEF       0     12.00
K         5      9.00
QB        1     10.48
          14     1.68
RB        8     24.90
          2     18.80
TE        7      0.00
WR        15    11.30
          11     8.80
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

However, that does not account for the `FLEX` "position"

I could alternatively loop through the dataframe and do this manually, but that seems very intensive.

How can I achieve the intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom function that select a number of players according your requirements for each group and keep this index as `idx_best`. Then exclude all already selected players and select FLEX other players as `idx_flex`. Finally extract the union of this two indexes.

```
FLEX = requirements_dictionary['FLEX']
select_players = lambda x: x.nlargest(requirements_dictionary[x.name])

idx_best = df.groupby('Position')['Score'].apply(select_players).index.levels[1]
idx_flex = df.loc[df.index.difference(idx_best), 'Score'].nlargest(FLEX).index

out = df.loc[idx_best.union(idx_flex)].sort_values('Score', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
             Player Position  Score
8   Darrel Williams       RB  24.90
2       Mark Ingram       RB  18.80
3    Michael Carter       RB  16.20
4      Najee Harris       RB  15.30
0     Buffalo Bills      DEF  12.00
15    Davante Adams       WR  11.30
1     Aaron Rodgers       QB  10.48
5        Tyler Bass        K   9.00
11      Corey Davis       WR   8.80
7    T.J. Hockenson       TE   0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I hadn't considered trying to bake in a solution using `index.levels`. However, this does not yield the intended solution as posted in the question.

Comment: The only difference is I have 2 QB because there are 2 QB in your input dataframe. So I don't understand why there is only one in your outcome. How to exclude Matt Ryan?

Comment: The `requirements_dictionary` specifies the number of each position required in the final dataframe, with the difficulty being that the position of `FLEX` could be one of many. That is why I posted this challenging question.

Comment: @wundermahn. Can you check my new output please. It seems what you expect, right?

Comment: why does flex matter in your code?  flex is not in the dataset

Comment: @GoldenLion. FLEX is here to select 2 other players that are not previously selected in `idx_best`. We take the next two best ranked players after the 8 (sum of QB, RB, ...). Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

use the requirements dictionary to get the rows equal to a position then sort by score and get the head equal to the dictionary value for the position.  Flex is top 2, for position in RB, WR, TE.  I concatenate the flex results. my solution is more intuitive and logical to understand

```
txt="""Player,Position,Score
Darrel Williams,RB,24.9
Mark Ingram,RB,18.8
Michael Carter,RB,16.2
Najee Harris,RB,15.3
Buffalo Bills,DEF,12
Davante Adams,WR,11.3
Aaron Rodgers,QB,10.48
Tyler Bass,K,9
Corey Davis,WR,8.8
T.J. Hockenson,TE,0"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt),sep=',')
requirements_dictionary = {'QB': 1, 'RB': 2, 'WR': 2, 'TE': 1, 'K': 1, 'DEF': 1, 'FLEX': 2}
#print(df)
df_top_rows = pd.DataFrame()
for position in requirements_dictionary.keys():
    df_top_rows = df_top_rows.append(df[df['Position'] == position].sort_values(by='Score', ascending=False).head(requirements_dictionary[position]))
print(df_top_rows)

position='FLEX'
df_flex_rows = df_top_rows.append(df[df['Position'].isin(['RB','WR','TE'])].sort_values(by='Score', ascending=False).head(requirements_dictionary[position]))

#print(df_flex_rows)
df_result=pd.concat([df_top_rows,df_flex_rows],axis=0)
df_result.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(df_result)
```

output

```
       Player Position  Score
6    Aaron Rodgers       QB  10.48
0  Darrel Williams       RB  24.90
1      Mark Ingram       RB  18.80
5    Davante Adams       WR  11.30
8      Corey Davis       WR   8.80
9   T.J. Hockenson       TE   0.00
7       Tyler Bass        K   9.00
4    Buffalo Bills      DEF  12.00​
```